# MVC Web API - CORS Policy not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-mvc-4, cors

I have created a simple Web API in our existing MVC application (By adding an API controller). I hosted API  to localhost and created an simple html page to call the service and to check CORS. To enable I changed my web.config file with following lines:

```
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
```

Everything was working fine and API was accessible through html page to localhost.

With same changes I hosted it on server (shared hosting server). It is throwing the same irritating error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mywebsite.com/api/Booking. Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

According to search on Google it should work with these web.config changes. Please help to resolve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try what's mentioned here - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api ?

Comment: No, I followed this article : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617892/Using-CORS-in-ASP-NET-WebAPI-Without-Being-a-Rocke

Comment: Why not follow the official document ? Give this a try.

Comment: Actually it worked on IIS on local host that's why didn't try. I will try once the official link

Comment: My existing application targeting framework 4.0 and the nuget package that need to installed require 4.5. A lot of changes required. still not able to understand why web.config changes didn't work on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after spending a full day resolved the issue, followed link posted by "Yaser".

But I would say it is **not easy** that's why I am mentioning steps here.

1. First of all we need to install package through Nuget "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" but if your target framework is 4.0 you cannot install it. First convert into 4.5 by right click on Project => Properties then  in application tab select framework 4.5
2. The another gotcha is most of dll's will not work after changing framework version, again Right click on solution and select on Manage Nuget Package and update all. (take back up your project before doing this)
3. if everything works fine you are just one step away - add the following line in webapiconfig.cs under app_start folder

   **config.EnableCors();**

After that open you API controller, add following line at controller level

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class BookingController : ApiController
{
}
```

Last step change your web.config on production server add following line (compare with localhost web.config)

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

All make a new build and replace all the bin files with new one ........ :)

Thanks